EF Core: TPH and mapping derived's type property to the same table column
Another question about TPH inheritance mapping and how EF decides to map properties into columns.
Suppose that you have the following table:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GuiaTransporte](
    [IDGuiaTransporte] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Data] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [IdLocalTrabalhoOrigem] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IdLocalTrabalhoDestino] [int] NULL,
    [IDFornecedor] [bigint] NULL,
    [IdFuncionario] [int] NULL,

/* other columns removed*/

    [version] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_GuiaTransporte] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 

) ON [PRIMARY]


And you have the following classes:
// base class for derived types
public abstract class GuiaTransporte : Entity, IVersionamento {
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }

    public string Tecnico { get; set; } = "";

    public LocalTrabalho LocalOrigem { get; set; } = new ( );

    public DateTime DataTransporte { get; set; }

    public string Observacoes { get; private set; } = "";

  // other properties removed
}

public class GuiaTransporteLocalTrabalho : GuiaTransporte {

   public LocalTrabalho LocalDestino { get; private set; } = new ( );

    public Funcionario? Funcionario { get; private set; }
}

public class DocumentoAfetacao : GuiaTransporte {

   public Funcionario FuncionarioAfetacao { get; private set; } = new();
        
    public LocalTrabalho LocalDestino { get; private set; } = new();

}


And now, I'm trying to apply the following mappings:
public sealed class GuiaTransporteTypeConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<GuiaTransporte> {
    
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<GuiaTransporte> builder){
        builder.ToTable("GuiaTransporte");

        builder.HasKey(g => g.Id);
        builder.Property(g => g.Id).HasColumnName("IdGuiaTransporte");

        builder.Property(g => g.Version).IsConcurrencyToken( );

        builder.HasDiscriminator(g => g.TipoGuia)
               .HasValue<GuiaTransporteLocalTrabalho>(TipoGuiaTransporte.LocalTrabalho)
               .HasValue<GuiaTransporteFornecedor>(TipoGuiaTransporte.Fornecedor)
               .HasValue<DocumentoAfetacao>(TipoGuiaTransporte.Afetacao);
        builder.Property(g => g.TipoGuia)
               .HasColumnName("TipoGuiaTransporte");

         // other properties
    }
} 

public sealed class DocumentoAfetacaoTypeConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<DocumentoAfetacao> {
    
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<DocumentoAfetacao> builder) {
        builder.HasBaseType<GuiaTransporte>( );

        builder.HasOne(g => g.FuncionarioAfetacao)
               .WithMany( )
               .HasForeignKey("IdFuncionario");
        builder.Navigation(g => g.FuncionarioAfetacao).AutoInclude( );
        
        builder.HasOne(g => g.LocalDestino)
               .WithMany( )
               .HasForeignKey("IdLocalTrabalhoDestino");
        builder.Navigation(g => g.LocalDestino).AutoInclude( );
    }
}

public sealed class GuiaTransporteLocalTrabalhoTypeConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<GuiaTransporteLocalTrabalho> {
    
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<GuiaTransporteLocalTrabalho> builder) {
        builder.HasBaseType<GuiaTransporte>( );

        builder.HasOne(g => g.Funcionario)
               .WithMany( )
               .HasForeignKey("IdFuncionario");
        builder.Navigation(g => g.Funcionario).AutoInclude( );
     
        
        builder.HasOne(g => g.LocalDestino)
               .WithMany( )
               .HasForeignKey("IdLocalTrabalhoDestino");
        builder.Navigation(g => g.LocalDestino).AutoInclude( );
    }
}


As you can see, I have 2 derived types and each one maps its Funcionario and ´LocalTrabalho` properties to the same table's column. Well, this works flawlessly with NH but EF seems to ignore one of the mappings, ie, when I try to map each derived type's navigation property to the same column, only one of the mappings is applied (and EF uses a convention for the other). Here's the generated SQL for each of the derived types:

/* GuiaTransporte */
INSERT INTO [GuiaTransporte] ([Data], [DataTransporte], [GuiaTransporteLocalTrabalho_IdFuncionario], [GuiaTransporteLocalTrabalho_IdLocalTrabalhoDestino], [IdLocalTrabalhoOrigem], [Observacoes], [Login], [TipoGuiaTransporte], [Version])
      OUTPUT INSERTED.[IdGuiaTransporte]
      VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8);


/* DocumentoAfetacao */
 INSERT INTO [GuiaTransporte] ([Data], [DataTransporte], [IdFuncionario], [IdLocalTrabalhoDestino], [IdLocalTrabalhoOrigem], [Observacoes], [Login], [TipoGuiaTransporte], [Version])
      OUTPUT INSERTED.[IdGuiaTransporte]
      VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8);

As you can see, EF insists on using the typename_foreignkeyname for the second of the derived type's instead of using the specified foreign key.
Can anyone help? Can't I map 2 navigation properties from derived types into same column?
Thanks.

You need to use shadow property.
Working example:
public class Metadata 
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}

public abstart class Docunent 
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}


public class Doc1 : Document
{
    public virtual Metadata Metadata { get; set; }
}

public class Doc2 : Document
{
    public virtual Metadata Metadata { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Document> Documents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Metadata> Metadatas { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
            .HasDiscriminator<int>("Discriminator")
            .HasValue<Doc1>(1)
            .HasValue<Doc2>(2);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Doc1>()
            .HasOne(d => d.Metadata)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("MetadataId")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Doc2>()
            .HasOne(d => d.Metadata)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("MetadataId")
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Doc1>()
            .Property<int>("MetadataId")
            .HasColumnName("MetadataId");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Doc2>()
            .Property<int>("MetadataId")
            .HasColumnName("MetadataId");
    }
}

